# Find the shaded area

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, circles, area

Find the shaded area
[image]

Here is the equation that i've made
\begin{align*}
S&=\pi R^2\\
S_1&=\pi {R_1}^2\left(\frac{24}{360}\right)\\
S_2&=\pi{R_2}^2\left(\frac{24}{360}\right)
\end{align*}

then,
\begin{align*}
S_1-S_2&=\text{ shaded area}\\
S_1-S_2&= \pi  {R_1}^2\left(\frac{24}{360}\right)-\pi {R_2}^2\left(\frac{24}{360}\right)\\
     &= \pi 4^2\left(\frac{24}{360}\right)-\pi 1^2\left(\frac{24}{360}\right)\\
     &= 16\pi \left(\frac{24}{360}\right) - \pi  \left(\frac{24}{360}\right)\\
     &= \frac{16}{15}\pi -\frac{1}{15}\pi\\
     &=\pi 
\end{align*}
Answer: $\pi$

I feel my equation is wrong, but I don't know what's wrong with it.

Also,  i am wondering the way to do this kind of question is changing the area degree to radiuss first or we dont need to.

Comment: sorry I forgot to upload my picture, now here it is!

Comment: @RossMillikan My bad, thanks! I am always bit worried while I am doing some edit, that I will miss something. Sometimes I just go through few questions in my spare time. Should have paid more attention to what I was doing!

Answer (score 2):

You have done fine.  What do you think is wrong?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MTurgeon:  OP asked what was wrong.  I think this is an answer to the question.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess it's just a matter of personal taste, but I feel this could have been simply a comment.

Comment: @MTurgeon:  Then the question stays in the unanswered queue and gets brought back up by the robot.

Comment: Sure, whatever. But you still asked for clarification ("what do you think is wrong?") and I thought it was MSE policy to ask for clarification through comments, not answers.